# Multiple reference in the same brackets in Elsevier

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, multiple-citations

I am using the LaTeX format of Elsevier which is available on their website. I am unable to put multiple references in the same bracket for instance, [1-5]. Do you have any idea to do it particularly in Elsevier's LaTeX format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sort&compress` option.

```
\biboptions{sort&compress}
```

and then cite

```
\cite{ref1,ref2,ref3}
```

See page 3 of this [documentation](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf).

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein and Second Author",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\biboptions{sort&compress}
\begin{document}
Like this. \cite{dirac,latexcompanion,einstein}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Each `\bibitem{<bibitem>}` is turned into a macro `\b@<bibitem>`, so you can use that to extract the number of the citation. I've wrapped a reference to this macro inside `\specialcite`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialcite}[1]{\@nameuse{b@#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See \cite{abc}, or \cite{abc}-\cite{ghi}, or [\specialcite{abc}-\specialcite{ghi}].

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc

  \bibitem{def} Def

  \bibitem{ghi} Ghi
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

You may want to use `\mbox{[\specialcite{<from>}-\specialcite{<to>}]}` in general in order to avoid the reference sequence breaking at the line end as a result of the hyphen `-`.