# Many references for citing in one bracket

Tags: citing, natbib, elsarticle

I use bibliographystyle as elsarticlenum and I want to show [1,2,3] as [1-3]. What should I do for solving this issue? I am not sure if I change the style I can run without error.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[font={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}


% packages for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
% packages for tables
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]



%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}


%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{natbib}




%\usepackage[numbers,super]{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{numbers,super}



\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]



%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{\ensuremath{#1^\circ}}

\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{\footnotesize{#1}}}

\newcommand\myfootnote[1]{\footnote{\small{#1}}}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}


\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\usepackage{calc,ragged2e}
\hyphenation{gauss-ian}

\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}


\journal{XXXXX}


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}


Different ML techniques have been used for predicting the mechanical attributes of the conventional concrete in numerous studies \cite{shang2022predicting, solhmirzaei2020machine, behnood2020machine}.

\end{document}
```

```
@article{shang2022predicting,
  title={Predicting the Mechanical Properties of RCA-Based Concrete Using Supervised Machine Learning Algorithms},
  author={Shang, Meijun and Li, Hejun and Ahmad, Ayaz and Ahmad, Waqas and Ostrowski, Krzysztof Adam and Aslam, Fahid and Joyklad, Panuwat and Majka, Tomasz M},
  journal={Materials},
  volume={15},
  number={2},
  pages={647},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}



@article{solhmirzaei2020machine,
  title={Machine learning framework for predicting failure mode and shear capacity of ultra high performance concrete beams},
  author={Solhmirzaei, Roya and Salehi, Hadi and Kodur, Venkatesh and Naser, MZ},
  journal={Engineering structures},
  volume={224},
  pages={111221},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}



@article{behnood2020machine,
  title={Machine learning study of the mechanical properties of concretes containing waste foundry sand},
  author={Behnood, Ali and Golafshani, Emadaldin Mohammadi},
  journal={Construction and Building Materials},
  volume={243},
  pages={118152},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `\usepackage{cite}` work? If not, post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing the problem.

Comment: I use \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} actually. I don't know how to make [1-4] works. It has also hyperref.

Comment: \usepackage{cite} removes all the citations

Comment: I get [1-4] with `\usepackage{cite}\usepackage{hyperref}` (use that order; hyperref always goes last) and `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} `. Try re-running pdflatex, then bibtex then pdflatex two more times. Again if it still doesn't work, post a complete minimal example. Otherwise, there is no way for us to guess what is going wrong.

Comment: Which document class do you employ? `elsarticle`, maybe? Please advise.

Comment: \documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle} %\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle} . I put the code

Comment: @\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} does not work with \usepackage{cite}. The references are disappeared at all. Please look my packages

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460331/multiple-reference-in-the-same-brackets-in-elsevier   i think this is my case

Comment: I edited the question to include code tags and fixed the misspellings in the the title; also see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natbib package's options `numbers,sort&compress` will have the desired effect.

You're loading the natbib package twice; the document class elsarticle loads it, and then you load it again later on. You can remove the later `\usepackage{natbib}` and pass the options to it directly to the documentclass's options:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review,numbers,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```

Or else you can suppress elsarticle loading natbib and load it yourself:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review,nonatbib]{elsarticle}
..
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

In the future, when you're asked to produce a minimal working example, take the task seriously. Remove all the unnecessary packages, comments, command definitions, and make sure the document works as is. What you posted has no `\bibliography` command, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. Nice done!